# Edit profile error in php

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi guys, I'm doing a personal project and need help. I want users to be able to edit their profile, but it is giving me an error, to see if you can find it, I pass the code and the error**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
    function verificarUsuario($id) {
        $sql_leer = 'SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE id = '.$id.' AND usuario = '.$_SESSION['usuario'].' ';

        $gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
        $gsnet->execute($id);

        if ($gsnet->fetchColumn() > 0) return true;
        return false;
    };

     /* Se cargan los datos del usuario para mostrar en el FORM */

  $sql_leer = 'SELECT id,equipo,email,pass,thumb FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '.$_SESSION['usuario'].'';

  $gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
  $gsnet->execute();

  $resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();

?>

<form method="POST" action="editar_usuario.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Equipo" name="equipo" value="<?php echo $resultado['equipo']?>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $resultado['email']?>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass" value="<?php echo $resultado ['pass']?>">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen" name="thumb" value="<?php echo $resultado ['thumb']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultado['id']?>" >
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Editar</button>
        </form>
```

> Error:

```
             <form method="POST" action="editar_usuario.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Equipo" name="equipo" value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: equipo in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\perfil.view.php</b> on line <b>160</b><br />
">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\perfil.view.php</b> on line <b>161</b><br />
">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass" value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: pass in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\perfil.view.php</b> on line <b>162</b><br />
">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen" name="thumb" value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: thumb in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\perfil.view.php</b> on line <b>163</b><br />
">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\perfil.view.php</b> on line <b>164</b><br />
" >
```

> Archive editar_usuario.php
>
> include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';
>
> /* FUNCION GENÉRICA VALIDACIÓN USUARIO */
>
> $id = $_POST['id']; function verificarUsuario($id) {
>       $sql_leer = 'SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE id = '.$id.' AND usuario = '.$_SESSION['usuario'].' ';
>
> ```
> $gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
> $gsnet->execute($id);
>
> if ($gsnet->fetchColumn() > 0) return true;
> return false; };
> ```
>
> /* Si nos viene POST realizamos un cambio en los datos */ if
>   (isset($_POST['id'])) {
>       $data = [
>           'equipo' => $_POST['equipo'],
>           'email' => $_POST['email'],
>           'pass' => md5($_POST['pass']),
>           'thumb' => $_POST['thumb'],
>           'id' => $_POST['id']
>       ];
>       $sql_editar = 'UPDATE usuarios SET equipo=:equipo, email=:email, pass=:pass, thumb=:thumb WHERE id=:id';
>       $sentencia_editar = $pdo->prepare($sql_editar);
>       $sentencia_editar->execute($data);
>
> ```
> /* Verificación usuario. Si no es válido redirecciona. Si es válido continua */
> if (!isset($_POST['id']) || !verificarUsuario($id)){
>     header('Location:home.php');
>
> }     };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `isset()` on every variable. `isset()` is used to check whether the variable have value or not. you have to add `isset(`) for all input values.

Refer one example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Equipo" name="equipo" value="<?php echo isset($resultado['equipo'])? $resultado['equipo']:''; ?>">
```

Comment: nuevo error al editar para actualizar los datos en la base de datos:
Notice: Undefined index: thumb in D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\editar_usuario.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\editar_usuario.php on line 26

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\editar_usuario.php on line 26

Comment: $pdo is an database connection object. you should creat connection with database.

Comment: This is conexion to BBDD include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer,  I didn't get that line from your code.